# ld: framework not found Lightning

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, lightning

I'm trying to add the lightning framework to my Xcode project, and the project is not building with an error:

> ld: framework not found Lightning
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I'm working in the `.xcworkspace`, and I've tried to do use the commands pod deintegrate, pod install. I've also tried deleting the framework from Linked Frameworks and Libraries and readding but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

Try basic solutions like clean Xcode (press Cmd+Shift+K ), close Xcode and reopen If doen't help remove framework , do pod install and add again your framework and pod install ...